# Need to redirect non-www and/or http to www AND https

Tags: redirect, web-config

Plain asp website.  Need to redirect non-www to www AND http to https. 
Found another post that was close but doesn't completely work. It works for root entries only but if there is anything beyond the root site name then the redirect does not work at all.
For example --

non-www will redirect properly to https and www
non-http will also redirect properly to https and www

But domain.com/categories.asp?cat=130 will not redirect and will simply stay on the non-https, non-www page.
Any fix for this redirect?

```
Here is the code that I used:

<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>

<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
    <add key="on" value="https" />
    <add key="off" value="http" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK -- I added this after my http to https and this works:

```
--
<rule name="Canonical name" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:1}"  redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```